Manhwa where the temperature increases and the main character has a shelter
In this manhwa the temperature increases +100°C and everyone is dehydrated.
The main character is the only one with water and a cold room.

It's "The doomsday ruthless man starts hoarding trillions of supplies"

The earth is affected by unknown energy, the core expands, and natural disasters and doomsday come. Extreme heat, earthquakes, volcanic eruptions, floods, severe cold... natural and man-made disasters come one after another! Su Chen struggled through the apocalypse and finally entered the safe zone, but was betrayed by his girlfriend in the end! Reborn and returned to one month before the end. This time, I only live for myself!


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe this manhwa and perhaps provide a link so we can see how it matches the question?

You're referring to this video on YouTube.



The video is a ripoff of a webtoon where the opposite happens; Global Freeze: I Created An Apocalypse Shelter

The world is plunged into an icy age, and 95% of humanity is wiped out! In his previous life, our hero Zhang Yi was tragically killed by the very people he helped, thanks to his kind heart. But fear not, for Zhang Yi has been reborn and now possesses the awesome power  – space manipulation! He's gone completely bonkers hoarding supplies for the icy apocalypse and is ready to rule the frozen wasteland! He vows to unleash a hundred times the pain on those who harmed him in the past!

